# Preserve vim marks across a file copy

Tags: vim

I have a file with a set of marks.  They are stored across vim sessions via viminfo.  No problems there.  However, when I copy the file elsewhere (especially under a different name), the marks are lost because there is now a new entry for the file in vim info.

[Edit]: I'm using MacVim

So, foo.txt has a set of marks.  When I copy it to bar.txt, the marks are lost.

My question, therefore, is:

How do I preserve marks across file copies.

The Capital marks [A-Z] don't seem to be the answer, as expected.

I also tried using a template to do this, but when the template is loaded, the marks in the template are not.

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you make the copy from within Vim, using the `:saveas` command, marks should be preserved. This method also migrates the undo history, if you're using persistent undo.

Comment: that works, and is a very acceptable solution!  Ideally, I'd like to do a 'copy' -> ':w', as opposed to a 'open original' -> ':saveas', since, I can script a command to do the copy properly, but ':saves' is perfectly acceptable.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could suggest doing this is to ensure the mark information was copied for a specific file.

You could do this in one of two ways (at least).

First, you could create a `vimcopy` program which both copies the file to a new destination *and* duplicates the marks with `viminfo`.

Second, you could create a new alias along the lines of:

```
vimas <newfile> <oldfile>
```

which would do the duplication before opening up the new file.

Both require a fair bit of thought on your part to ensure the correct actions are performed.

Comment: Yup - that is along the lines of what I was thinking.  I was thinking of manually adding the required marks to vim info (at the right spot) via a shell sed script post copy.  Seems like a hack, though, but, short of creating a custom module, I'm not sure how else to proceed... Thanks!